# integral gaussian divided by gamma

Tags: probability-distributions, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I am trying to get the pdf of a Gaussian plus a Poissonian variable. I used the correlation between their pdfs to get the new pdf and got stuck at this integral.

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{at^2+bt+c}}{\Gamma(t+1)}dt$$

I've tried some integration techniques, but ran out of ideas. Any thoughts or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Are you sure that this is *the* integral you need? Poisson distribution is discrete, so I'd expect a sum somewhere. Also, having a $\frac{1}{\Gamma(t+1)}$ for a variable $t$ is quite uncommon for probability distributions.

Comment: Well, I might be wrong but what I did was to use the continuum version of poisson distribution like this $$ \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}= \int_0^\infty \delta(u-x) \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^u}{\Gamma(u+1)}du$$

Comment: I'd say your *continuous version* should have the density $x\to e^{-x}x^k /\Gamma(k+1)$. Also, take a look at Gamma distributions. I don't think that the function you wrote is a probability density.

Comment: I think you are right. I'll try a different approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49291/how-to-compute-the-pdf-of-a-sum-of-a-discrete-and-a-continuous-random-variable. Thanks!